# pandoc 2.1 YAML metadata and table-of-contents in docx

Tags: yaml, docx, pandoc, tableofcontents

I'm wondering if there is ant way to have the title page, author details, and , that is set in the document `YAML metadata` block. Ideally, I would want the title page and author details on the first page, the  on the second page, with a level 2 header i.e., `## Abstract`, and the `table-of-contents` preceding the main body of the document.

A similar questions has been [asked on this forum previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591517/pandoc-inserting-pages-before-generated-table-of-contents), but this didn't really resolve my issues (or at least I could see a way to apply it to my question).

I am converting from `.md` to `.docx` with a custom `.docx` template. I am using [`pandoc 2.1`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc), [`Scriver 3`](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/introducing-scrivener-3), with the [`Scrivomatic`](https://github.com/iandol/scrivomatic)+[`Pandocomatic`](https://github.com/htdebeer/pandocomatic) workflow.

Many thanks in advance.