# Chapter(s) before table of contents in Bookdown PDF output

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown

I'd like for a chapter to appear before the table of contents (but after the title page) in the `pdf_book` output of `Bookdown`.

One way to do this is to add the chapter to a `.tex` file and and link it using `before_body:`. However, this means the chapter will not appear in `gitbook` (which I also need). I'd prefer not to keep both a `.tex` and `.Rmd` version of the same chapter.

An ideal solution would be if the chapter could be kept in a `.Rmd` file, and its contents extracted into the `before_body` for `pdf_book`. That way it's still available for `gitbook`. Though I'm not sure how I might do that, or indeed if it's possible?

Is there a solution? Or is it exceeding the limits of `Bookdown`'s flexibility?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I guess you could put `\tableofcontents` somewhere in your markdown, and remove it from the [pandoc template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates)...

Comment: ah yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591517/pandoc-inserting-pages-before-generated-table-of-contents

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can trigger ToC creation manually in the document, which gives more control over its placement. Of course, automatic table of contents creation should be disabled:

````
---
title: "MWE"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: False
---

```{r child = 'file-you-want-to-include.Rmd'}
```

```{=latex}
% Trigger ToC creation in LaTeX
\tableofcontents
```

# Rest of your document starts here
````

The downside is that this only works with PDF output, not HTML.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Because the ToC in `gitbook` runs along the side of the page, its position relative to chapters is not relevant, so your solution is still suitable. Looks like the position of the list of figures, and/or list of tables, can also be set using `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, respectively.

Comment: Great solution. Note that the `\tableofcontents` command could just be added without the ```{=latex}``` box, because latex commands get ignored when output is html.