# How can I change the placement of Table of Contents in a Quarto book project?

Tags: latex, quarto

I am using Quarto inside RStudio to create a book project. The output will be a pdf/LaTeX file. Quarto originally puts the Table of Content just after the title page. But I need to put the abstract, preface and acknowledgements first before the Table of Contents. How can I change this sequence? Is it possible to change this sequence using `_quarto.yml` file or do I need to change it through *LaTeX*?

Comment: This related Q&A may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52416703/2425163

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [template-partials](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html#template-partials)

To do that you need to create a `before-body.tex` file as a partial latex template and put all the necessary latex code that will go before the table of contents, list of figures, list of tables, and rest of the document.

---

**before-body.tex**

```
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\frontmatter
$endif$

$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------
%   Abstract
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\Large{Abstract}
\end{center}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

This is the Abstract part

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------
%   Preface
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\Large{Preface}
\end{center}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

This is the Preface part

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------
%   Acknowledgement
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\Large{Acknowledgement}
\end{center}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

This is the acknowledgement part

\newpage
```

---

Then to add this template, use the `template-partials` option in `_quarto.yml`

**_quarto.yaml**

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Quarto book"
  author: "Shafee"
  date: "7/31/2022"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd

format:
  pdf:
    toc: true
    documentclass: scrreprt
    template-partials:
      - before-body.tex
```

---

**Also, create the partial file named exactly as `before-body.tex`, since per the documentation,**

> Note that the name of the partial files is important. You choose which portion of the template to replace by providing a partial with that name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my Quarto/LaTeX problems.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. And so far, I thought upvoting means accepting your answer. But after your comment, I saw that there is a tick mark symbol too, to accept the answer. Really sorry about that.

Comment: This solution is a pdf only solution. You need to write the content before the toc as LaTeX. Hence you no longer can generate both a pdf and an HTML from the same source code.

Comment: @Thierry, yes this is a pdf only solution (and I believe the OP wanted to solve this for pdf only) but I think its also possible to do in case of HTML too, since quarto also provides [`HTML partials`](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html#html-partials)

Comment: @shafee what if I have a parameter that I want to include? E.g., say in the preface, I want to mention something like, "Hello `r first_name`. Usually, the rmarkdown takes the values based on the variables.