# position of table of contens and searchable files with Quarto (PDF output)

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, quarto

is there a Quarto way to

- place the table of contens (TOC) where I like it. Like for references ([Bibliography Generation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/footnotes-and-citations.html#bibliography-generation))

```
::: {#refs}
:::
```

(for LaTeX please see answer in comment from @shafee for further information)

````
toc: false 

```{=latex}
\tableofcontents
```
````

- create Copy-paste-able/searchable PDF files [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-cpy-srchpdf)

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mmap}
```

- replace default title page, is there something like `toc: false`? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

```
\begin{titlepage}

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the TOC, for example?

Comment: @shafee after a cover sheet (is there such a thing?) and/or legal and address information

Comment: Well, if that's the case, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310404/10858321),  where you put the code for cover and address, just like the case for abstract, and preface.

Comment: thank @shafee ```{=latex}
\tableofcontents
``` works